# What's the location of a C# compiler on SharePoint Server?

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I'm on a SharePoint server and I need to compile a small change to my C# code. Where can I find the C# compiler on the SharePoint Server? I know .NET is installed by virtue of the fact that it is a SP server, but I'm unable to find .NET or the C# compiler I'm looking for. It isn't in any locations such as C:/Program Files or Windows/system like the following article suggests.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78f4aasd.aspx

I'm sure I'm overlooking something obvious but thanks for helping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The .NET 2.0 C# compiler csc.exe (which will work for .NET 2.0 to 3.5) is located at `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727`. If your version of SharePoint runs on .NET 4.0 then it'll be in `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319`

Answer (score 4):

It should be in `%WINDOWS%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\%VERSION_NUMBER%`.

For example, on my box I have:

```
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v1.0.3705
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v1.1.4322
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.0
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319
```

Of these, only the 2.0.xxx, 3.5 and 4.0.xxx directories have C# compilers (csc.exe) within them.

Rather than invoking the executable directly, could you use [`CSharpCodeProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.csharp.csharpcodeprovider.aspx) to compile the code? That way you can do it all programmatically without having to work out the location of the executable.

Comment: Thanks Jon. I'm trying to do this quickly so whatever is the easiest for a one time thing. It looks like for CSharpCodeProvider that I'd have to first compile the CSharpCodeProvider code I wrote, then compile the other program with it. P.S. I appreciate all the extra info, but since Duncan did answer first I marked his as the answer. +1 for the help.

Comment: @KyleM: Ah, I thought you were trying to do this *from* your code in the first place...